# Changing the color of string Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am defining a string and now I want to set my string a color, please show how do I do that with my code

```
  final String followOnLabel = inningScore.followOn! ? ' (f/o)' : '';
```

I want to set my string followOnLabel color or textstyle. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are text. They don't have colors. Widgets have colors. To give a `Text` widget a red text you could write this for example:

```
Text(followOnLabel , style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red))
```

Answer (score 0):

@SaDev As I understand, do you want to change the colour of your string depending on the condition? If yes then the below code will help you to meet your requirements.

```
Text(
 followOnLabel,
 style: TextStyle(
     fontFamily: /*Font Family*/,
     color: inningScore.followOn! ? Colors.yellow : Colors.red)
)
```